# Url Pattern for specific war files (apps) in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I have 3 war files deployed on my tomcat (9) server. I have recently added SSL configuration and works fine and auto-redirects all http requests to https.

The problem is that I need to redirect only some apps to https. Other(s) should work with http and https. They open as:

- https://example.com/frontApp/index.do
- https://example.com/backOne/index.do
- https://example.com/backTwo/index.do

backOne and backTwo shouldn't redirect to https.

I have tried various `<url-pattern>` in web.xml but nothing seems to achieve the above mentioned scenario.

```xml
<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
 <url-pattern>/frontApp</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <user-data-constraint>
 <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
 </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

```xml
<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
 <url-pattern>/backTwo</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
 <user-data-constraint>
 <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
 </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

Have gone through a lot of questions here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281587/ssl-for-specific-pages-url-patterns-in-tomcat) is the closest but I can't figure it out.

Sorry if answer is obvious and I can't see it. Don't have a lot of experience with tomcat.

Comment: Can you clarify which `web.xml` file(s) you are referring to? The app-specific ones in each web app's `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, or only the Tomcat file in `conf/web.xml` file?

Comment: It is ```conf/web.xml```

Comment: OK - then definitely follow the guidance in the answer by @hiranchaudhuri - there should be no need to modify that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the constraint for confidential data transfer into the frontApp's web.xml. As you do not redirect the others do not put such a constraint into them. There is no need to modify the global server configuration.